# Chrome local ports hack or virus?

Tags: google-chrome, virus

Chrome freezes when I connect to secure websites, such as my email and bank.

[image: Image of Ports problem]

1. Task manager shows dozens of chrome.exe processes still live, even five minutes after Chrome is closed. I have to forcefully kill them.
2. Netstat shows strange local ports (see attached image), such as “Local Port 1110 nfsd-status” and “Local Port 1034 Activesync” connected on 443.

I removed any Chrome extensions and uninstalled / updated to the latest Chrome. So, it’s got to be malware. But Windows Defender, Malwarebytes, Gridin Malware Protection, and Comodo didn’t spot anything.

Comment: _"So, it’s got to be malware"_ - you're jumping to conclusions way too quickly.

Comment: Your Windows appears to be seriously “customized”. None of the outgoing ports Chrome is using are from the default ephemeral port range (49152-65535). Was it perhaps upgraded from Windows XP?

Comment: Customized? Nope, straight Win 10 Pro install (from latest Media Creation tool) that worked great until this port thing started showing up.

Comment: It’s still working great. Please provide the output of `netsh int ipv4 show dynamicport tcp` (run it in Command Prompt).

Comment: Output is:
Protocol tcp Dynamic Port Range
Start Port      : 1024
Number of Ports : 64511

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing are names for well-known ports. Like port 80 being HTTP or port 443 being HTTPS. Or rather, what someone decided the name should be, because port 1110 isn’t “nfsd-status”. Either way, this does not mean Chrome is suddenly speaking NFS or anything like that.

You can check the list yourself, [here](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml)

These ports are used by Chrome because it uses the operating system’s [ephemeral port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port) range. By default, starting from Windows Vista, this is 49152-65535. However, on your system, it was changed to be 1024-65535. This is not necessarily a malicious change.

You can [change it back](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929851/the-default-dynamic-port-range-for-tcp-ip-has-changed-in-windows-vista) using an *elevated* command prompt:

```
netsh int ipv4 set dynamicport tcp start=49152 num=16384
netsh int ipv4 set dynamicport udp start=49152 num=16384
netsh int ipv6 set dynamicport tcp start=49152 num=16384
netsh int ipv6 set dynamicport udp start=49152 num=16384
```

However, this will not solve any hangs or whatever. You should open a new question about that, with further investigation about which websites (HTTP, HTTPS, …) are affected, whether it’s working on a different PC/smartphone/tablet on the same network, whether other browsers on the same PC are affected….

Keep in mind that depending on the Chrome extensions/apps you have installed, the process may remain in the background for quite some time.

Also, I suggest not using any third-party security software at all.

Comment: That's interesting. I was about to try it, but I found an unknown service called Mobile_Series and disabled it, and the port range shifted back.Still looking into it.

Comment: It reverted back after reboot, so I used the netsh command, and I'll keep an eye on it for the next couple of days.

Comment: OK, that solved the ports question.